# build opencv 3.0 for android with extra modules

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I built the OpenCV 3.0 beta with extra modules. The build was without java libraries and that was the only way that I was able to build the OpenCV 3.0 beta without getting errors and there is no problem because I only need the native part.

The problem that I have is when I try to implement the text module I get an error that the library can´t be resolved. The line to implement the library is this:

```
#include <opencv2/text.hpp>
```

So my question is: What can I do to resolve this problem? Do I have to move some include files to some location?

Comment: did you run a `make install` ? that should have copied all the header files to your build/install folder

Answer (score 0):

Note that `OCRTesseract` class (inside of [opencv2/text.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/text/include/opencv2)) provides an interface with the tesseract-ocr API (v3.02.02) in C++ and it is compiled only when [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is correctly installed.

First of all you should compile tesseract (and its dependencies) to Android.